# Kill Process On List Of remote Workgroup Servers

Tags: powershell, wmi, credentials, remote-server, get-wmiobject

I have a list of 5 Servers and for specific reasons they are not on the domain. The credentials among them are the same.

I am trying to remotely kill any instance of a process on the machines. For this website I have change the process to notepad.exe

I am having issues trying to determine how to successfully connect to these boxes.

I am running

```
$StartCheck = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Computer $Servers |
  Where-Object { $ProcessNames -contains $_.Name }
$StartCheck | FT * -a;$StartCheck | FT * -a | out-file -FilePath $logfile -Append
```

and Here.

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Computer $Servers |
  Where-Object { $ProcessNames -contains $_.Name }).Terminate() | out-null
```

I am faced with the following error

```
Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
(E_ACCESSDENIED))
At C:\Users\first.last\Desktop\Kill All Traffic Managers.PS1:67 char:13
+ $EndCheck = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Computer $Servers |
+
```

What is the easiest way to enter the credentials?

Comment: I forgot to mention I can PING and UNC to the machine in question from the server I am running the script from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your script and change usernname and P@ssw0rd

```
$account = "username"
$PASSWORD = ConvertTo-SecureString P@ssw0rd -AsPlainText -Force
$UNPASSWORD = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential $account, $PASSWORD
```

Also change your

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Computer $Servers`
```

for

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Computer $Servers -Credential $UNPASSWORD
```

Comment: When this is run it returns.
Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
(E_ACCESSDENIED))

how would I make it so that I can pump the username and password right to it. I do not want to have any manual intervention as it will be run from an automation platform.

Comment: It depend do you want your username and password in plain text in your script ?

Comment: Also let me remind you that this script is being run on a domain machine against NON Domain machines.

Comment: for this script plain text is fine. This will only be used in a dire situation to bring everything down before we manually bring it back up.

Comment: Hmmm I am getting the exact same error message. when trying with other machines that are on the domain it works fine even without the -credentials. but not against this workgroup machine.

Comment: I feel like this is an issue with the connection between the domain and the workgroup computer

Comment: the user you've use is admin on the workgroup computer ?

Comment: The quotes around the password were getting included. I removed them and this resolved the issue.